# React Native | renderRow function returns React Component that doesnt update when datasource is changed

Tags: listview, react-native

I set a new data source and the renderRow function is called.

If i return a simple View like { task.task_name } the list is updated and in the names are seen in the correct order.

But if return a React component, in my case, i return a , where i pass data via props, the data source is correct, but the TaskListItem component is not updated.

Works: return { task.task_name }

Dont Work: return

Cheers

---

```
Global: 
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })

constructor(props) {
  super(props)   
  this.state = {
    tasksDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.tasks)
  }
}

renderRow={(task) => {
  return this._renderTaskRow(task)
}}

_renderTaskRow(task) {
  return <TaskListItem task={ task } playing={ true } />
}

On hideRow function i set the new data source like this:

this.setState({
   tasksDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(newTasks)
})
```

Comment: Hey, can you post your `renderRow` function, your `constructor` or `getInitialState` function, and your `setState` function (for the datasource)? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe try `return this._renderTaskRow.bind(this, task)` . Or if not, maybe show your `ListView` component as well for more insight.